# ignore messages in Jenkins console/FIPS integrity verification test failed

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, fips

Could you help me please and let me know if there is a plugin for Jenkins which lets me to hide specific messages in console output in the jobs?

For example in every build I see "FIPS integrity verification test failed" and I want to get rid of that.How to do it for all jobs or specific?

I know what is FIPS and how to enable/disable it localy on the machine but want to hide it in Jenkins,not to disable it on the machine.

Cheers and thank you very much in advance.